# possible bug with wrapfig (just before section starts)

Tags: wrapfigure

I appear to have come across a bug using `wrapfig`.  If I use a `wrapfig` environment immediately before a `\section{...}` command, then I get some bad behaviour, which appears to go away if I add some text after the `wrapfig` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
\missingfigure{}
\caption{a figure}
\end{wrapfigure}

%This text fixes it.
\section*{Lorem}


\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

This gives [image]

Note the extra space in the final paragraph.  If however I uncomment "This text fixes it", I get

[image]

I did a (brief) search and found nothing about this.  What's going on?

Comment: No wonder. Just place `wrapfigure` *after* the section title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `wrapfig` tells you not to place a `wrapfigure` immediately before a list environment. The problem with `\section` is, however, the same: both `wrapfigure` and `\section` set `\everypar`, which means “fail”.

Just add `wrapfigure` *after* the section title.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section*{Lorem}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.6\textwidth}
\missingfigure{}
\caption{a figure}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]