# Another way to wrap text around an image, including headings

Tags: graphics, xetex, wrapfigure, wrap

This is a MWE of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3.1cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \section{A section}

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following result:

[image: Output of given LaTeX code.]

That's nice, although I wanted to use the remaining space of the section, as it'll be short enough for a small image to be used.

I used `wrapfigure` (`wrapfig` package), but as @egreg stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/293987/101590), it's not possible to put a `wrapfigure` before headings.

Is there another way to wrap text around an image, including headings?

Thanks in advance! `:)`

**Update.-** Here's a sketch of what I mean by wrapping the image with text, including the header:

[image: Graphical explanation of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: If you are certain there is sufficient space, you can use `insbox` as shown in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119478/paragraph-indentation-incorrect-with-picinpar-package/253733#253733). However, this cannot cut into the text of the next section, so it is up to you to ensure there's enough space.

Comment: @cfr Ouch... Sounds difficult, but promising. Let me try it!

Comment: Isn't that what the `\vspace` answer does?

Comment: @cfr Yeah, unfortunately I haven't found a way to also "move" the text so it could fill the blank space below the image.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `\baselineskip`? I don't think that has anything to do with the `\vspace` solution, does it?

Comment: @cfr In fact, both of them lead to the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the objection to [user94293's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329005/). If the problem is the vertical space underneath the picture, You can adjust it by removing some or all of the `\baselineskip` there.

For example,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
  \vspace{-1.5cm}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \vskip -\baselineskip
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: less space]

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately, I can't choose both answers. They are so useful! `:(`

Answer (score 2):

Just add `\vspace{-...}`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3.1cm}
  \vspace{-1.5cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\section{A section}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice... But how can I "update" the configuration to fill the left space with text? Is that posible?

Comment: @JBFWP286 Which `left space` do you mean?

Comment: @cfr The space next to the heading (the space left as blank, *not* explicitly at the left of, say, the heading). It's the one at *the right*, like in this answer.

Comment: You mean you want text to the right of the header and the left of the image @JBFWP286 ? That would look very odd, wouldn't it? In any case, it has nothing to do with wrapping the image, really. That would be blank anyway.

Comment: @cfr Nope, I'm sorry I didn't explain myself correctly. I'll update my question to show you.